# how to send approval email automatically from dropdown value selected using sharepoint list workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list with some data field.Now I have to choose some name from dropdown.Everytime when i filled up all the data field and click for submission,then an approver email should go that perticular person from dropdown value.Please suggest me the list workflow process about this

Answer (score 1):

You can create SharePoint Designer Workflow to achive this.
If you are not aware how to create please follow [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125120/Step-by-Step-Guide-in-Developing-your-own-Workflow)
In SharePoint Designer do setting mentioned in screenshot below
[image: Procedure Image]